# How to use nested locale folder for i18next

Tags: typescript, i18next, react-i18next

I'm trying to reorganize my locale folder on my project. I want to separate my big locale files into smaller files and organize them into folders, but i18next doesn't seem to read those nested files.

For context, I'm using CRA with i18next, typescript and i18next-resources-for-ts.

I tried

```
const { t } = useTranslation("nested/file");
```

But ts just doesn't recognize it, and of course it doesn't work. Only if I change it to

```
const { t } = useTranslation("file");
```

does it stop complaining, but the problem is there will still be some duplicated names so I cannot really use "file" as a namespace for it.

Edit: on a side note, `i18next-resources-for-ts` seems to not working properly when I have 2 files with the same name but different nesting level (for example `file.json` & `nested/file.json`, it might indicate that nesting the files like this is not intended to work (?)

Comment: Unfortunately, I think `i18next` only supports the `language` (as folders) and `namespaces` (as files) hierarchy, though you can surely separate locale files under the same language folder as much as you like.